# Remove protrusions lines

Tags: python, opencv

I have an binarized image that is the contour of an object after HED edge detection and thinning with cv2.ximgproc.thinning.
I would like to remove the protrusions lines from the contour.
The lines have 1px

[image: 1]

Comment: Use hough line transform to get the 4 long lines and draw them on a black background.